# storyboard error with uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard

I am getting this error while trying to create my app structure with story boards

> static table views are only valid when embedded in
>   UITableViewController instance

I have created this sotry board that has a Navigation controller and then several views that branch off the main view that has a tableview in it.

one of the views that I have made off the main view has this error.. I have several other views with the same set up but none of them are having this issue yet.. im woudnering if I resolve this issue then they will say the same thing after as it was the first view I set up..

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say view, I'm assuming you mean UIViewControllers. For static tables, your view controller needs to be (must be) a UITableViewController, which is a subclass of UIViewController that handles tables, specifically static tables in your case.

Comment: Perfect.. this is just what I had started doing.. and once I replaced all of the viewcontrollers the error went away. thanks very much

Answer (score 5):

I was able to put a static UITableView inside my UIViewController by simply dragging the UITableView onto my ViewController in IB, and hooking both the delegate and data source to my view controller and then implement  (even if i'm using a static table, just to make Xcode shut up)

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
  @property (strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@end
```

If you wanted to put multiple UITableViews inside your ViewController with IB, you could create separate files/classes for each UITableView, and then hook them up as delegates. I see a bunch of answers that insist you must subclass from UITableViewController and it's just not the case.

```
@interface MyTableViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Cheers Ryan, I also ended up using a UIViewController and hooking up the data source and delegate.. cheers for the reply :)