# Static Table View error without having any static tables

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am getting the following error:

> Static table views are only valid when embedded in
>   UITableViewController instances

The problem is that I only have two tables in my app and both are set to dynamic. I don't know where the error is coming from.

[image: Static Table View Error]

Comment: For starters add the reuse identifier...

Comment: That wasn't the question. Thats a different tableView.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746161/storyboard-error-with-uitableview